# How do I modify my method to print the entire string instead of just one element in my binary tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

so I've managed to construct my `string` method to be able to print the elements from my binary tree but the issue is that I want it to print the entire binary tree as *one* string not the elements separate. My attempt is creating a list which appends the elements and then just prints the list.

When I try this approach the problem is that when getting the elements from the tree the list only prints the latest element, i.e length = 1. When I tried creating the list globally everything is fine but I ofc want to avoid global variables. I'll link the entire code but specifically its the `string` method that needs fixing. The code linked is with the global list `l1`.

```
l1 = []

class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor for the binary tree."""
        self._root = None
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
        self._size = 0
        self.l = []

    def add(self, root):
        """Add a given element to the binary tree."""
        if self._root:
            if root < self._root:
                if self._left is None:
                    self._left = BinaryTree()
                self._left.add(root)
                self._size += 1
            elif root > self._root:
                if self._right is None:
                    self._right = BinaryTree()
                self._right.add(root)
                self._size += 1
        else:
            self._root = root
            self._size = 1

    def string(self):
        '''Prints the entire tree as a string.'''
        #current = self._root
        if self._left:
            self._left.string()
        #print(self._root)
        l1.append(self._root)
        if self._right:
            self._right.string()
        return l1

    def len(self):
        '''Returns the size of the tree (# of elements in the tree).'''
        return self._size

def new():
    """Creates new instance."""
    return BinaryTree()

def main():
    test = new() # Test for new BT
    test.add('c')
    test.add('b')
    test.add('a')
    print(test.string())
    assert test.len() == 3

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the global variable to accumulate the result, you can `return` the nodes from the recursive calls & accumulate in the calling method.

See the `traverse` method I've defined. It's doing an in-order traversal of the tree. The `string()` method just becomes the `str()` of the result returned by `traverse()`.

```
class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor for the binary tree."""
        self._root = None
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
        self._size = 0
        self.l = []

    def add(self, root):
        """Add a given element to the binary tree."""
        if self._root:
            if root < self._root:
                if self._left is None:
                    self._left = BinaryTree()
                self._left.add(root)
                self._size += 1
            elif root > self._root:
                if self._right is None:
                    self._right = BinaryTree()
                self._right.add(root)
                self._size += 1
        else:
            self._root = root
            self._size = 1

    def traverse(self):
        '''Prints the entire tree as a string.'''
        to_print = []
        if self._left:
            to_print.extend(self._left.traverse())
        to_print.append(self._root)
        if self._right:
            to_print.extend(self._right.traverse())
        return to_print

    def string(self):
        return str(self.traverse())

    def len(self):
        '''Returns the size of the tree (# of elements in the tree).'''
        return self._size


def new():
    """Creates new instance."""
    return BinaryTree()


def main():
    test = new()  # Test for new BT
    test.add('c')
    test.add('b')
    test.add('a')
    print(test.traverse())
    assert test.len() == 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Very nice thank you, however is the str(self.traverse) function of the list really needed in the string method? I can just use the traverse method and print the return for the list too right?

Comment: Added since one you expect a method called `string` to return a `str`. It is optional as far as functionality is concerned

Answer (score 0):

You can use your original code only a small change to method string.

Need to add list 'll' as a default parameter and past it down on recursive calls as follows.

```
  def string(self, ll = []):
        '''Prints the entire tree as a string.'''
        #current = self._root
        if self._left:
            self._left.string(ll)
        #print(self._root)
        ll.append(self._root)
        if self._right:
            self._right.string(ll)
        return ll
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your `string` method by incorporating iteration into your class. If such a technique is used, calculating the size of the structure can also utilize the feature as shown in the `__len__` method shown down below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
def main():
    test = Node()
    test.add('c')
    test.add('b')
    test.add('a')
    print(test)
    assert len(test) == 3


class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes a single node to be used in a Binary Tree."""
        self.__data = None
        self.__left = None
        self.__right = None

    def add(self, data):
        """Incorporates a data value into the Binary Tree structure."""
        if self.__data is None:
            self.__data = data
        elif data < self.__data:
            if self.__left is None:
                self.__left = type(self)()
            self.__left.add(data)
        elif data > self.__data:
            if self.__right is None:
                self.__right = type(self)()
            self.__right.add(data)

    def __str__(self):
        """Converts a Binary Tree into a string suitable for printing."""
        return ''.join(map(str, self))

    def __iter__(self):
        """Iterates over all values in the underlying tree structure."""
        if self.__data is not None:
            if self.__left is not None:
                yield from self.__left
            yield self.__data
            if self.__right is not None:
                yield from self.__right

    def __len__(self):
        """Counts how many data values are stored in the underlying tree."""
        return sum(1 for _ in self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For a more interesting test of the Binary Tree, you can read each character from the source file and add that to the structure. Three items can be added to the code to accomplish this:

1. `import sys`
2. A `main` function modified to get characters from the file.
3. An `update` method that can help with handling iterable objects.

---

```
import sys


def main():
    test = Node()
    with open(sys.argv[0]) as file:
        test.update(character for line in file for character in line)
    print(test)
    print('There are', len(test), 'unique characters in this file.')


class Node:

    def update(self, iterable):
        """Takes all items from an iterable and adds them to the tree."""
        for item in iterable:
            self.add(item)
```

Make sure that you add the `update` method to the `Node` class. What is shown up above is incomplete but shows the code that needs to be added to give the Binary Tree extra functionality.